# Leibniz rule for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, leibniz-integral-rule

I am struggling to find whether there exists something like the Leibniz rule (interchanging integral and derivative) for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals.
Does such a result exist? If so, how to use it?

In particular, how do we calculate

$\frac{d}{dx}\Big( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dF(t) \Big)$?

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x dF(t) = F(x) - F(0)$, and its derivative does not exist unless $F$ is differentiable.  If $F$ is good enough (absolutely continuous?), then $dF(t) = F'(t)\,dt$ and we can apply the standard Leibniz rule.  I suppose there remain intermediate cases where $F$ is differentiable but not absolutely continuous?

Comment: Yes I am indeed interested in these intermediate cases.

Comment: The derivative might not exist, e.g. when $dF(t)$ is a dirac delta measure.

Comment: Okay, but what conditions do we require for it to exist and how do we calculate it under these conditions?